# c++ derived base class Friend function accessing private on Parent?

Tags: c++, inheritance, visual-c++, friend

Please consider the scenario below:

```
    class A 
    { 
     friend void B::Itemfunction();
     private:
     int number;
     int size;
     public:
     Randomfunction();
    }

    class B : public A
    {
     private:
     string Random;
     public:
     void Itemfunction();
     void CheckLog();

    }
```

Would it be possible for an object made in Itemfunction of type A to access the private data members of obj? Such as:

```
    void B::Itemfunction(){
    A obj;
    //Possible to do...
    obj.number = 2;
    }
```

I understand that the derived class B can access all the public parts of A, but if I wanted just one function (Itemfunction) to access the private parts would this be the correct way of doing it? I just want to see if my understanding is correct.

Cheers

Answer (score 4):

No, it's not possible. You cannot friend a class member function for a class that isn't yet completely declared.

The only way in that case (since `class B` needs a completely declared `class A` to inherit), is to forward declare `class B;` and friend the whole class:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

    class B;

    class A 
    { 
     // friend void B::Itemfunction();
     friend class B;
     private:
     int number;
     int size;
     public:
     void Randomfunction();
    };

    class B : public A
    {
     private:
     std::string Random;
     public:
     void Itemfunction();
     void CheckLog();

    };

int main()
{   
}
```

[<kbd>Live Demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c8b50d87613f44e8)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clear explanation! Much appreciated - I may have to make B a friend of A for this to work then it seems.... didn't realize the need to forward declare - great tip!

Comment: Then it is preferable to make that member protected instead of private and not make whole class friend.

Comment: @Slava sorry could you explain why that is? Due to data hiding?

Comment: @afc_1995 `friend` gives `B` total and unfettered access to all of `A`, and this includes parts of `A` that should be left in `A`s complete control. `B` can mess with `A`'s state without the awareness of `A`, potentially leaving `A` in an inconsistent state.

Comment: [Also read up on coupling.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_(computer_programming)), though with inheritance you're already tightly coupled.

Answer (score 3):

In your code, where you implement `Itemfunction`, you are creating a new, completely unrelated object of type `A` locally. In inheritance, your `B` object has an internal subobject of type `A`. You can access the fields of `A` directly within `B`. However, you can't access private members. Your friendship trick will not work; you cannot declare a method of `B` a friend until you see `B`s definition, but `B` can't be defined until `A` is defined, and as you can see we're going in circles. What you can do instead is to make that member protected:

```
class A 
{ 
  protected:
  int number;
  private:
  int size;
  public:
  Randomfunction();
}

void B::Itemfunction() {
  number = 2;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, ah i see the issue of going in circles now.  I guess apart from the solution you have described, making class B a friend of A should also work right? Or would there be problems in being a derived class and a friend?

Comment: Think on the needs of your program. If `A` friends `B`  so that `B` has access, then what of children `C` or `D`? The friendship will not scale as you add subclasses. [`protected` access will](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/access), if that is what you want.

Comment: @afc_1995 `protected` is designed to solve this exact problem, so you should really use `protected`. If `B` is friends with `A`, it gets to access everything, including private members. The whole point of having both protected and private is so that A can decide what its children have access to. Is there any reason why you prefer friendship to protected?

Answer (score 0):

This has a chicken and egg problem. Both `B` must be fully defined for `A` to see `B::Itemfunction`.

```
class A
{
    friend void B::Itemfunction(); <-- Itemfunction does not exist yet
private:
    int number;
    int size;
public:
    int Randomfunction();
};

class B: public A
{
private:
    std::string Random;
public:
    void Itemfunction();
    void CheckLog();

};
```

Swapping the order won't work either because `B` needs `A` to be defined to inherit from `A`.

```
class B: public A <-- A does not exist yet
{
private:
    std::string Random;
public:
    void Itemfunction();
    void CheckLog();

};

class A
{
    friend void B::Itemfunction();
private:
    int number;
    int size;
public:
    int Randomfunction();
};
```

Solution 1 is forward define `class B` so the compiler knows that B exists, even if it knows nothing about it, and then `friend` the whole class, because `A` only knows `B` exists. OP's `friend` relationship is maintained.

```
class B; <-- forward definition of B
class A
{
    friend class B; <-- friending all of B, not just the function 
private:
    int number;
    int size;
public:
    int Randomfunction();
};

class B: public A
{
private:
    std::string Random;
public:
    void Itemfunction();
    void CheckLog();

};
```

**BUT!** All of `B` now has complete access to all of `A`. If `A` wants to keep `size` or any other members hidden and under it's control, tough. `B` can call all of `A`'s functions and change all of `A`'s member variables. `B` can totally pown `A`.

This also doesn't scale to other subclasses. `B` can see all of `A`, but `C` and `D` cannot.

So say you have a less trivial example where `A` cannot allow anyone to mess with the value of `size`. Maybe it's the capacity of an internal array, and changing `size` will result in `A` running past the end of allocated memory. The reason doesn't matter much here; for the sake of this example no one but `A` is allowed to change `size`.

This leads us to solution 2: [protected access](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/access) and accessor functions.

```
class A
{
protected: <-- all inheritors can access members in this block. No one else can
    int number;
private: <-- only A can access members in this block
    int size;
public:
    int Randomfunction();
    int getSize() <-- accessor function to provide read-only access to size
    {
        return size;
    }
};

class B: public A
{
private:
    std::string Random;
public:
    void Itemfunction(); <-- can do anything to number and read size
    void CheckLog(); <-- so can this

};

class C: public A
{
private:
    std::string member;
public:
    void doStuff(); <-- and this
    void DoOtherStuff(); <-- and this

};
```

`B` and `C` can access `A::number` and can use `A::getSize` to see the value of `size`. `number` can be changed by `B` and `C`, but `size` cannot. If you are worried about the cost of calling a function to read `size`, don't be. When the compiler is done with `A::getSize`, you won't even know it's there. It probably isn't.